# Control Windows 8 with a tablet

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, ipad, touchscreen

It seems much of Windows 8 is based on the idea that it will be running on tablets, and touch screen PCs. I like this, but I don't have a W89 tablet, or a touch PC yet.

I'm running W8 on a laptop, and am wondering if there's any way of using my iPad2 as a touch interface with metro?

Or another options that'd be nice is if there's a input device similar to Apple's "Magic Trackpad" that would allow me to use hand gestures instead of a mouse cursor when in metro apps.

I've seen some cool videos of MS Smart Glass and it would seem that the capabilities are there. But it may just be too early on to do this? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any Android device to emulate multi-touch on Windows 8, here is how you will do it:

1. Install [**TUIOdroid**](https://code.google.com/p/tuiodroid/) on your Android device.
2. Install [**EcoTUIODriver**](https://github.com/ecologylab/EcoTUIODriver) by Interface Ecology Lab on your Windows 8 machine.

I am the original author of the second piece of software, so if you have any questions you can ask them here directly. Also, there is another alternative called multitouchvista, but I don't know about its compatibility with Windows 8.